# *char value changing on the function

Tags: c, string, char

I'm trying to use a function with an *char.

```
 //the function
  void init_player(struct player *_player, int pos_x, int pos_y, char *sprite){
      printf(" %s",sprite);
      _player->pos_x = pos_x;
      _player->pos_y = pos_y;
      strncpy(_player->player_sprite, sprite, sizeof(100));
  }
```

When I print the function before using the funcion it is all right.

```
   //the call
   struct player array_player[3];
   char *str = "img/dragon_verde.bmp";
   printf("%s",str);
   init_player(array_player[0],0,0,str);
```

Here are the print results:

```
 Before function: img/dragon_verde.bmp
 After function : )!Sjdnm
```

(something like that after function, can't copy it)

I hope you understand my English.

Comment: note : `sizeof(100) == sizeof(int)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem here:

```
init_player(array_player[0],0,0,str);
```

It should be:

```
init_player(&array_player[0],0,0,str);
```

**Note that if you had enabled compiler warnings (and paid attention to them) you would have noticed the mistake immediately.**

Comment: thank you so mutch. I have Codeblocks on a Virtual machine and I could not enable compile warnings yet.

Comment: You really should enable compiler warnings before you write any more code - the warnings will save you a lot of time and effort which you would otherwise spend debugging silly mistakes in your code.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
strncpy(_player->player_sprite, sprite, sizeof(100));
```

makes no sense, `sizeof(100)` will evaluate to `sizeof (int)`, probably 4 on most common platforms. Perhaps you thought of `(size_t) 100`, which casts the integer 100 to the proper type for the third argument to `strncpy()`: that's very redundant though and you should not write it like that. Just trust that implicit conversion from `int` to `size_t` of a value such as `100` will work.

The proper way to write it, if `player_sprite` is a character array (i.e. there's something like `char player_sprite[100];` inside the `struct player` declaration, is:

```
strncpy(_player->player_sprite, sprite, sizeof _player->player_sprite);
```

Otherwise you need to find another way to have the proper buffer size.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(100)` is not equal to value `100`. it's `sizeof int` which is `4`.
when you use partial copy while strncpy you should manually append it with `'\0'` at the end or it will cause undefined behavior.

change the size appropriately as per your needs. as other unwind said use sixeof the copying to string or send the number of characters to be copied when you call the function(as one of the parameter)

[Check this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/) it will give a idea of how to use strncpy.